# Find and Remove MongoDB TTL Index

Tags: mongodb

I created a TTL index on a collection probably a year ago and I can't remember what I called it. I'm finding that I no longer need it and would like to delete it. How do I find and delete this TTL Index? Using `db.collection.getIndexes()` only provides vague names and none seem like the name I used at the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to do this myself. But there is no command to filter out only the TTL indexes. So I just looped through the indexes and find the TTL indexes by `expireAfterSeconds` property.

```
var ttlIndexes = db.ttldemo.getIndexes().filter(function(i){ 
    return i.hasOwnProperty('expireAfterSeconds');
});
```